# Monitoring services of EC2 Windows instance using AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I have monitored performance counters such as memory, free disk etc using CloudWatch custom metrics. Can I monitor the services using CloudWatch? I have checked the features which cloud watch monitors but found nothing related to monitoring services. I just need to monitor whether the service is running or not and send a notification when the state of the service changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but out-of-the-box solutions like the [EC2Config Windows Integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-configuration-cwl.html) you alluded to aren't as readily available for service-level custom metrics.

CloudWatch Custom Metrics allow you to extend CloudWatch with your own defined metrics and data, so you can reasonable implement them yourselves to monitor your own services. Your service can write metrics data to CloudWatch itself, or you can write another process that monitors your service and writes metrics based on responses from your service to CloudWatch.

---

Per your edits, to publish CloudWatch custom metrics for an arbitrary set of windows services will require some windows-specific powershell, because we can't assume that the service will have a web endpoint to ping.

You'll want to create a service monitor that evaluates your services via `Get-Service`, and then publishes a data point to a CloudWatch custom metrics if they are running.

Here is an example implementation in PowerShell that will write custom metrics for services with a name matching `*YOURSERVICENAMESHERE*` every 300 seconds. If you want to run this for *every service on the EC2 instance*, you can replace this with the wildcard `*`, but this may be expensive at scale. It may also require some tweaking if too many services are on the box, because you can only send so many metrics at a time via `Write-CwMetricData`. See code comments for details on that.

By only creating a data point on success, you establish a 'failure' condition (INSUFFICIENT_DATA for X seconds) that you can use to create CloudWatch Alarms that satisfy your notification constraint.

This script MUST be run on a Windows EC2 instance with [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) installed and configured:

```powershell
Param
(
    [string]$Period = 300,
    [string]$Namespace = 'service-monitor'
)

# Use the EC2 metadata service to get the host EC2 instance's ID
$instanceId = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")

# Associate current EC2 instance with your custom cloudwatch metric
$instanceDimension = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension;
$instanceDimension.Name = "instanceid";
$instanceDimension.Value = $instanceId;

# "Job" loop; write to CloudWatch and then sleep for the interval defined by the period variable above, in seconds.
while($true)
{
    $metrics = @();

    $runningServices = Get-Service -Name *YOURSERVICENAMESHERE* | ? { $_.Status -eq 'Running' }

    # For each running service, add a metric to metrics collection that adds a data point to a CloudWatch Metric named 'Status' with dimensions: instanceid, servicename
    $runningServices | % { 
        $dimensions = @();

        $serviceDimension = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension;
        $serviceDimension.Name = "service"
        $serviceDimension.Value = $_.Name;

        $dimensions += $instanceDimension;
        $dimensions += $serviceDimension;

        $metric = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.MetricDatum;
        $metric.Timestamp = [DateTime]::UtcNow;
        $metric.MetricName = 'Status';
        $metric.Value = 1;
        $metric.Dimensions = $dimensions;

        $metrics += $metric;       

        Write-Host "Checking status for: $($_.Name)"        
    }

    # Write all of the metrics for this run of the job at once, to save on costs for calling the CloudWatch API.
    # This will fail if there are too many services in metrics collection; if this happens, just reduce the amount of
    # services monitored, or edit this line into the above foreach loop and write each metric directly.
    Write-CWMetricData -Namespace $Namespace -MetricData $metrics

    Write-Host "Sleeping for $Period seconds."

    Start-Sleep -s $Period
}
```

Save this to a file and you can run it from the command line to begin writing metrics. Once you're comfortable with it, feel free to ditch the "while true" loop for a scheduled task or powershell job.

**Additional Resources:**

- [AWS Documentation - Scenario: Publish Metrics to CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/PublishMetrics.html) - A tutorial/walkthrough for publishing custom metrics for a hypothetical application. This would be a good place to get started learning how to publish your own custom metrics.
- [AWS Documentation - Publish Custom Metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html)
- [MSDN - Get-Service Cmdlet Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service)
- [AWS Tools For PowerShell Documentation - Write-CWMetricData](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Write-CWMetricData.html)

Comment: My requirement is not too complicated. It has to just monitor whether the service is running or not. That way, it has to monitor all services under the Services column of ec2 instance. And, one more thing, I wan to do this for Windows instances.

Comment: I have modified my question. Please check it out.

Comment: @prudhvi Your modification does not change my answer; to achieve this with CloudWatch, you will need to either find a 3rd party monitor that publishes CloudWatch custom metrics, or write a service monitor that publishes CloudWatch custom metrics. The linked documentation should be sufficient to get started.

Comment: Ok.. Shuld I write that service monitor in the json script where I wrote the Memory and FreeDisk metrics?

Comment: @prudhvi Are you referring to the [Windows EC2Config JSON for sending performance counters to CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-configuration-cwl.html)? If so, no, I don't think that supports custom metrics.  Your service monitor will need to invoke the CloudWatch API/SDK as part of its routine.  Generally, you'll want something to run on a schedule that pings your service, and if the ping succeeds then record a data point to your custom metric.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the same json file.

Comment: @prudhvi If you're wanting to monitor all windows services, you can do this with PowerShell and the AWS PowerShell Tools.  I'll update my answer with an example, one moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anthony. That would really help me as I am confused what to do.

Comment: @prudhvi Updated.

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony. I will try using this

Comment: Please check updated issue when free. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your instance is running a recent version of AWS Tools for PowerShell (so that you have all the correct class definitions) and make sure you're providing appropriate credentials to it, so it can write to Cloudwatch.

Comment: I would also caution against dramatically altering your question body in this way -- at some point, the problem you're facing deserves a new question so that you don't lose the scope of your original problem.

Comment: Regarding credentials, check this doc for details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html

Comment: @prudhvi Great! Sounds like you've almost got it.  The way this script is designed, a data point should only be added for running services, so that behavior is expected.  This *does* change the graph -- the lack of a new data point is, itself, data. With CloudWatch alarms you can encapsulate that by alarming on a state known in CloudWatch as "INSUFFICIENT_DATA", which will let you know both if your service stopped running, or if the service monitor itself stopped. So for example, for your service you can create an alarm for this metric where no data is available for some defined interval.

Comment: Please check this question out when free. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923602/integrating-cloud-watch-with-our-monitoring-tool/41924219#41924219 . Thanxx in advance

Comment: This saved a lot of my time. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Please note that this only works with IMDSv1. If you're using IMDSv2, you'll also need to get a token. AWS talks about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-service.html).